# Auto restart django development server on file save after previous error

Tags: python, django

While writing the code, I usually am in the habit of saving the file every minute or so. Sometimes, that leads to situations where the function is not complete, and I have saved it, causing the django development server to throw up an error like following:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by ...
Traceback
..
..
  File "/home/user/work/project/api/file.py", line 26
      def update_something(self, ) 
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Now in cases when the code is working fine, the django dev server auto-restarts on file save with reflected changes. How can I make the django server recover from the failed Error state and restart the server automatically on subsequent file saves?

Currently, I have to stop the `python manage.py runserver` command in terminal, and run it manually again.

I am using `django 1.5.3` on `python 2.7.6`

Comment: Don't save so often? Seriously, every ten seconds?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Well I was thinking of the same, but its more of a habit. Mostly I'm reading the code (say out of every 5 minutes around 4 are spent reading, 1 writing), and it is in those writing cycles that I tend to save every 10-15 seconds.

Comment: Depending on your editor, you can install a syntax checker that will show you any error before saving.

Comment: @Germano Thanks for your suggestion. I installed [pyflakes for vim](https://github.com/kevinw/pyflakes-vim), and it is somewhat helpful, but the original problem still remains.

Comment: I agree with Daniel. There really isn't a problem here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I use a simple bash script for this.  Here's a one-liner you can use:

```
$ while true; do python manage.py runserver; sleep 2; done
```

That will wait 2 seconds before attempting to restart the server.  Insert whatever you think is a sane value.

I usually write this as a shell script named `runserver.sh`, put it in my project root (the same directory with manage.py in it) and add it to the gitignore.

```
while true; do
  echo "Re-starting Django runserver"
  python manage.py runserver
  sleep 2
done
```

If you do this, remember to `chmod +x runserver.sh`, then you can execute it with:

```
./runserver.sh
```

Use `Ctrl-c Ctrl-c` to exit.

Answer (score 0):

On windows you may use a batch file,  write this as a batch script named runserver.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
setlocal EnableExtensions

:WHILE_0
if 1 EQU 1 (
  python manage.py runserver
  sleep 2
  goto WHILE_0
)
```

Then you can execute it clicking it or from the command line:

```
./runserver.sh
```